# Silverlight error when loading many rows from SQL database

Tags: silverlight, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, domainservices, basichttpbinding

I have a Silverlight application that's built with Entity Framework 4, a heap of Silverlight modules ans a Web project that contains my DomainService, Model and Web.Config.

I pull data from an local SQL Server whick works fine. One of my SL modules pulls data from a specific table, when I have more than 4000 rows in this table the application crashed and gives me the following error message. When it has around 1000 roes it works just fine.
So, I guess maybe the DomainService cant handle all the rows or maybe my binding settings in webconfig is wrong in some way.. What Can I do?

Err message:

{System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'LoadSiteCageData'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClass1b.b*_17(Object )

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
        <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings />
    <system.web>

    <httpModules>
                <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">

    </pages>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

</system.web>
<system.codedom></system.codedom>

<system.webServer>
    <modules>
                <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="MyService.Web.Service1.customBinding0">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyService.Web.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyService.Web.Service1.customBinding0" contract="MyService.Web.Service1" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you post your config, specifically the endpoint specification? By default there is a size limit (64kb?) to messages. You need to increase that.

Comment: I've added webconfig to the initial post, please help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the limit of the size of data that can come over the wire as long as basichttpbinding is concerned. It is 64k.

There are 2 options to work around this.

- Pull the data page by page
- Download the data as some comma separated file, parse and display

What I usually do is to download the data as zip file, unzip at client end and then process such large amount of data.

Comment: I cannot do this by paging, because all data I'm pulling is being plotted in a graph. So Zip is not an alternative either.

Comment: You can still page the data.  To do this, you will want to retrieve 50 or so records at one time.  Once all of the records are downloaded, you can plot them to your graph.

Comment: I'm fairly new to these concepts, so right now I do not see clearly how I should do that. So, basically I'm looking for the qucik fix on this one - if theres some kind of buffers etc I just can increase.